# Can't understand how to use graphicscene object in method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

This is a main part of my code to visualize checkers. The problem is in method `moving`. How can I get `self.scene` object in this function and transport it (`self.scene`) to use it in the future functions? Because, I have to use `scene` in my other modules , where are my logical part of the program to move my items.

I want to smth such as my commented line in moving function (scene = self,scene , but how do it without self object !!??)

In addition, I thought that I can do this with app object (`myapp` in RUN MODULE ), but when I start to do like `myapp.scene.removeitem()..`, my process was stopped at all.

**RUN MODULE**

```
import sys
from visual import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

    class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)

            self.ui=MainScreen()
            self.ui.setupMS(self)

    #if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=MyWin()
    #myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**MODULE VISUAL**

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

transform_dict_to_pix = { (x,y):( (x+1)*60 , (y+1)*60 ) for x in range(8) for y in range(8) }
transform_dict_to_08 =  { (x,y):( int((x/60-1)) , int((y/60-1)) ) for x in range(60,481,60) for y in range(60,481,60)}
class MyEllipse(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    last_click=()
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        MainScreen.click1=True
        MainScreen.click2=False
        self.setBrush(Qt.yellow)
        event.accept()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        coord=event.buttonDownScenePos(Qt.LeftButton)
        x=coord.x()
        y=coord.y()
        MyEllipse.last_click=(x,y,self)




class MyRect(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        event.accept() if MainScreen.click1 else event.ignore()


    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        coord = event.buttonDownScenePos(Qt.LeftButton)
        obj=MyEllipse.last_click[2]
        x1=MyEllipse.last_click[0]
        y1=MyEllipse.last_click[1]
        x2 = coord.x()
        y2 = coord.y()
        obj.setBrush(obj.color)

        MainScreen.moving(obj,x1,x2,y1,y2)


class MainScreen():
    click1 = False
    click2 = False

    @staticmethod
    def moving(obj,x1,x2,y1,y2):
        '''how can i do like that : self.scene.removeitem() without self object ??? How can i use my scene in methods similar to it !!!???'''

        '''scene=self.scene''' #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!PROBLEM !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


        x1=x1//60*60
        x2=x2//60*60
        y1=y1//60*60
        y2=y2//60*60

        print(f'x1 : {x1} ; y1 : {y1} \n x2 : {x2} ; y2 : {y2} ')
        x08_from,y08_from=transform_dict_to_08[(x1,y1)]
        x08_to,y08_to=transform_dict_to_08[(x2,y2)]

        move_x=x2-x1
        move_y=y2-y1


        obj.moveBy(move_x,move_y)



    def setupMS(self,MainWindow):

        self.scene=QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0,0,600,600)
        self.create_icons()
        self.create_checkers()
        self.labels_create()

        checkers = self.object_checkers()
        self.white_checkers = checkers[:13]
        self.black_checkers = checkers[13:]

        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)

        self.view.centerOn(0,0)

        self.view.show()



    def object_checkers(self):
        '''get all objects ()'''
        list_of_checkers=[]
        flagx = 65
        flagx2 = 125

        for i in range(65,205,60):
            for j in range(flagx2,545,120):
                #self.scene.addEllipse(j,i,50,50)

                item=self.scene.items(QRectF(j-1,i-1,52,52),Qt.ContainsItemBoundingRect)
                list_of_checkers.append(item[0])
            flagx,flagx2=flagx2,flagx

        for i in range(365,545,60):
            for j in range(flagx2,545,120):
                item = self.scene.items(QRectF(j - 1, i - 1, 52, 52), Qt.ContainsItemBoundingRect)
                list_of_checkers.append(item[0])
            flagx,flagx2=flagx2,flagx

        #print(len(list_of_checkers))
        #print (list_of_checkers)
        return list_of_checkers

    def labels_create(self):
        self.label1 = QLabel()
        self.label1.setGeometry(QRect(180,15, 240, 40))
        self.label1.setText("Player_1")
        self.scene.addWidget(self.label1)

        self.label2 = QLabel()
        self.label2.setGeometry(QRect(180, 550, 240, 40))
        self.label2.setText("Player_2")
        self.scene.addWidget(self.label2)


    def create_checkers(self):
        '''create object of figures on the deck'''

        flagx=65
        flagx2=125

        brush1=QBrush(Qt.blue)
        brush2=QBrush(Qt.darkMagenta)

        for i in range(65,205,60):

            for j in range(flagx2,545,120):
                #self.scene.addEllipse(j,i,50,50,brush=brush1)
                item=MyEllipse(j,i,50,50)
                item.setBrush(brush1)
                item.color=brush1
                item.setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt.LeftButton)
                self.scene.addItem(item)

            flagx,flagx2=flagx2,flagx

        for i in range(365,545,60):

            for j in range(flagx2,545,120):
                #self.scene.addEllipse(j,i,50,50,brush=brush2)
                item = MyEllipse(j, i, 50, 50)
                item.setBrush(brush2)
                item.color=brush2
                item.setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt.LeftButton)
                self.scene.addItem(item)

            flagx,flagx2=flagx2,flagx





    def create_icons(self):
        '''create icons of the deck'''
        x = 60;y = 60;w = 60;h = 60

        brush1 = QBrush(Qt.darkGray)
        brush2 = QBrush(Qt.black)

        flag = 0
        for _ in range(8):
            x = 60

            for __ in range(8):
                rect=MyRect(x, y, w, h)
                if flag :
                    rect.setBrush(brush1 )
                self.scene.addItem(rect)
                #self.scene.addRect(x, y, w, h, brush=brush1) if flag else self.scene.addRect(x, y, w, h)
                x += 60
                flag = 1 - flag
            flag = 1 - flag
            y += 60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your implementation, most of them related to the logic of the implementation.

First of all, you should set class attributes only if you need to write/read access the *class*, not its instancies.
Related to this, another problem is that you're trying to use a class method (ok, it's a `staticmethod`, but in this case doesn't matter that much, as it's *still* a **method of a class**), which obviously won't give you any access to any property of any of its instancies: in your case you are trying to access `scene`, but that's an instance attribute, which is completely unknown to the class.

To be able to track objects you'll need a better parent/child logic, possibly avoiding direct and absolute reference to parents from their children (and almost never to the parent's class!), by letting the parent to be "notified" by its children and let *that parent* handle what is necessary, whenever it requires it. This is very important, because you might have more "sibling" children that could require some interaction between them, and that responsibility should really be left to the parent, mostly because sometimes it's impossible (or too complex) for a children to know all its siblings and their state/attribute/capabilities, since they usually are managed from the parent itself.

Finally, a couple of other issues.
You're tracking the checkers objects using a collision/shape detection, which doesn't make much sense and makes it very difficult for debugging or future modifications; just add them as soon as you create them: if you don't use common and global variables for geometries and, someday, you need to change those values, you will need to change all of them in every place you used them, increasing the possibility of bugs, usually because you used the same value for other variables, which happens more often than one would think. I've edited the example code to show a more consistent solution to "unify" sizes while keeping the whole checkerboard creation always consistent.
Finally, you are subclassing QMainWindow, but in the initialization you used QWidget, which will surely create problems.

---

I created a small and very limited example that mimics yours. Be aware that it's not "play-ready", there's no turn control, and, like in your example, you can move every checker in every (free) space of the grid; that's it.
The concept behind this is that we know that only "grayed" (as in *valid*) grid slots can be used for checkers, so I'm adding each checker as a *child* of a usable grid slot rectangle item. Whenever I want to move one checker, I click it and move it by clicking on another empty grid slot, which makes that the new grid item a parent of the checker.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

gridSlotSize = 60
margin = 60
checkerSize = 50
checkerMargin = (gridSlotSize - checkerSize) / 2
gridCount = 8
gridSize = margin + gridSlotSize * gridCount + margin

class CheckerItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, player, parent):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRect(checkerMargin, checkerMargin, checkerSize, checkerSize)
        if player == 1:
            self.color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.darkMagenta)
        else:
            self.color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        self.activeColor = self.color.lighter()
        self.setBrush(self.color)

    def setActive(self, active):
        if active:
            self.setBrush(self.activeColor)
        else:
            self.setBrush(self.color)


class CheckerScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.__init__(self)
        self.setSceneRect(margin, margin, gridCount * gridSlotSize, gridCount * gridSlotSize)

        self.addRect(self.sceneRect())

        self.current = None

        self.grid = []
        self.white_checkers = []
        self.black_checkers = []
        for row in range(8):
            for column in range(8):
                # this is a "trick" to make the grid creation easier: it creates
                # a grid square only if the row is odd and the column is even, 
                # and viceversa.
                if (not row & 1 and column & 1) or (row & 1 and not column & 1):
                    # create a gridItem with a rectangle that uses 0-based 
                    # coordinates, *then* we set its position
                    gridItem = self.addRect(0, 0, gridSlotSize, gridSlotSize)
                    gridItem.setPos(margin + column * gridSlotSize, margin + row * gridSlotSize)
                    gridItem.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.lightGray))
                    self.grid.append(gridItem)
                    if 3 <= row <= 4:
                        # don't add checkers in the middle
                        continue
                    # create checkers being careful to assign them the gridItem 
                    # as a *parent*; their coordinate will *always* be relative
                    # to the parent, so that if we change it, they will always 
                    # be centered
                    if row < 3:
                        self.white_checkers.append(CheckerItem(0, gridItem))
                    else:
                        self.black_checkers.append(CheckerItem(1, gridItem))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # right button to deleselect
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            self.setCurrent()
            return
        # find items at the event position, in descending order, top to bottom
        items = self.items(event.scenePos())
        if not items:
            self.setCurrent()
            return
        if isinstance(items[0], QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem):
            # we found a checker!
            self.setCurrent(items[0])
        elif items[0] in self.grid:
            # we found a grid item!
            gridItem = items[0]
            if gridItem.childItems():
                # if it has a checker in it, select it!
                self.setCurrent(gridItem.childItems()[0])
            elif self.current:
                # no checker here, but if we have a previous one selected
                # we "move" it here, by changing its parent to the new grid item
                self.current.setParentItem(gridItem)

    def setCurrent(self, new=None):
        # if a previous checker is selected, deselect it
        if self.current:
            self.current.setActive(False)
        self.current = new
        if new is not None:
            # set the current checker!
            self.current.setActive(True)


class Checkers(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.player1Label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Player 1')
        layout.addWidget(self.player1Label)
        self.player1Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.checkerView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        layout.addWidget(self.checkerView)
        self.checkerScene = CheckerScene()
        self.checkerView.setScene(self.checkerScene)
        self.checkerView.setFixedSize(gridSize, gridSize)
        # set the Antialiasing render hints to paint "smoother" shapes
        self.checkerView.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.player2Label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Player 2')
        layout.addWidget(self.player2Label)
        self.player2Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    checkers = Checkers()
    checkers.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can you give me an additional explanation , why do you make ellipse item  a square baby? I can't understand , how do you use it and how it make code easier . Why you didn't create ellipse as independent figure ?

Comment: and how i will delete checkers from the scene, when the figures are beaten . I can do this only with scene object with method removeitem . But, how can i  do this ,to the fact i haven't any acess from figures methods or moves methods to self.scene .

Comment: I've explained the reason for making ellipse items as *children* of the grid items. You can just add them to the scene, it depends on you prefer to implement your program. You can access the scene from any object inside it by using `scene()`, but, as already said, you should **really** implement that logic *from* the scene, not its elements. Besides that, if I may, it seems that you are beginning to learn PyQt; maybe a checker program is still a bit out of your current skills, at least for an implementation that uses QGraphicsView.

Comment: yes i am begginner in PyQt . I have a logical part of checker (can play in console ) . I thought , that i could visualise it , but see , it is not clear for me , as i thought before .

Comment: Dealing with a graphical framework is very different than console programs, as it can be much more object oriented; you have to understand the hierarchy between graphical objects (widgets), their parents/children, and the main application, keeping their behavior as tight as possible: the program should handle the overall logic, not its children, meaning that a child (the checker piece, or the empty grid square) should only notify the program that it's been clicked, letting the program decide what to do, whether it's selecting a new piece or move an already selected one to a new position.

Comment: i think , that in your method mousePressEvent the third and the fifth 'if' do the same actions . Why we must  check if our grid have a child in 'fifth if' (gridItem.childItems()) , if we checked it in the ''third if'' (instance...) . After the 'third if' we know that our grid haven't any checkers , aren't it ?

Comment: They are not the same; while the first if you refer to is not strictly required for the selection, it is an additional aid for the user, because it makes possible to select a piece as long as you click on the square that contains it, no matter if you exactly click inside the ellipse or outside it.